# How does 'zip' with different iterators on the same generator (Using itertools.tee) does not run the generator again?

Tags: python, iteration, zip

I Don't understand how zip is working. How doesn't it run "calc" twice? How does it "knows" its the same iteration?

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: def calc():
   ...:     for i in range(5):
   ...:         print(i)
   ...:         yield i
   ...:

In [3]: i1, i2 = itertools.tee(calc())

In [4]: z = zip(i1, i2)

In [5]: for i in z:
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:
0
(0, 0)
1
(1, 1)
2
(2, 2)
3
(3, 3)
4
(4, 4)
```

I see I wasn't clear enough. I know what yiled does, that isn't the question. On every iteration, we should go over calc twice but if you look at the "print" you can see that it happens only once. The same happens when I use `next(i1)` before the 'zip' which makes it even more strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'magic' happens in `itertools.tee`.
`tee` doesn't return "regular" iterators:

```
>>> type(i1)
<class 'itertools._tee'>
```

The iterators `i1` and `i2` are still related and the function won't be called again for every iteration. After iteration (If it is the lead iteration) the value returned from 'calc' is saved and being returned to the upcoming matching iterations from the other iterators returned from `tee` (Can be more than 2 iterators. see itertools.tee).

ex: With the help of the method print, we can see calc is being called only once although I iterate 1 time with every iterator. Pay attention to the difference between the output in the first iteration and the second - "I calculated" printed only once which means the generator was called only once.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def calc():
...     for i in range(5):
...         print("I calculated: " + str(i))
...         yield i
...
>>> i1, i2 = itertools.tee(calc())
>>> next(i1)
I calculated: 0
0
>>> next(i2)
0
```

If you want to see the implementation, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) is an implementation in python with an explanation.
[here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c) is itertools (with tee) real implementation. This module is written in c. try looking on  `tee_fromiterable` and `itertools__tee_impl`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
calc() is a generator. Generators by design maintain the state between calls. `
"""

import itertools


def calc():
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        yield i


i1, i2 = itertools.tee(calc())
print(f'{type(i1)=}')
print(f'{type(i2)=}')
# itertools.tee Return n independent iterators from a single iterable. i.e.calc
next(i1)  # calc called yields the 1st result.

z = zip(i1, i2)  # calc called again here as a single iterable
# Calc has now yielded the last 4 values.

for i in z:
    print(i) 
# The yield function maintains state so:
next(i1)  # Returns a Traceback
```

Output

```
type(i1)=<class 'itertools._tee'>
type(i2)=<class 'itertools._tee'>
0
1
(1, 0)
2
(2, 1)
3
(3, 2)
4
(4, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ctynd\OneDrive\CodeBase\StackOverflowActivity\OldScratches\scratch_2.py", line 26, in <module>
    next(i1)  # Returns a Traceback
StopIteration
```

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Added code and comments

Answer (score 0):

In your case, because you ran next once, you consumed one iteration in the first iterator (i1) which is zero, and so the zip starts of with 1 for i1 and 0 for i2

See below similar test case with and without running next to demonstrate why in your case you zipped [0,1,2,3] with [1,2,3,4]:

```
#
# With running next
#
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b, c = itertools.tee(a)
>>> b
<itertools._tee object at 0x000001D5A60D7C80>
>>> next(b)
1
>>> next(b)
2
>>> zip(b,c)
<zip object at 0x000001D5A60D7D00>
>>> for i in zip(b,c):
...  print(i)
...
(3, 1)
(4, 2)


#
# Without running next
#
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b, c = itertools.tee(a)
>>> for i in zip(b,c):
...  print(i)
... 
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
>>>
```

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: I see what you're saying.

Comment: I posted a separate answer as i could not post my code in the comment

Answer (score -1):

It looks like zip is efficient at being able to distinguish different "itertools.tee" objects that are coming from the same tee call and hence decide there is no need to call the calc() twice.
On the other hand if you call tee itself twice as in the code below, you will see that zip will not know anymore that the inputs are not the same, and so it will call calc() twice.

```
>>> i1, i2 = itertools.tee(calc())
>>> i3,i4=itertools.tee(calc())
>>> z = zip(i1,i3)
>>> for i in z:
...  print(i)
... 
0
0
(0, 0)
1
1
(1, 1)
2
2
(2, 2)
3
3
(3, 3)
4
4
(4, 4)
>>>
```

Comment: I found it. Added the right answer. Its not the 'zip' function.